# Taking a screenshot with C\GTK

Tags: c, gtk, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the entire screen with C and GTK. I don't want to make a call to an external application for speed reasons. I've found Python code for this ([Take a screenshot via a python script. [Linux]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux/782768#782768)); I just need to figure out how to do that in C.

Comment: It rather looks like that Python code you linked to is a good crib into the GTK API calls you will need to use in C.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Between that and the gnome-screenshot code, I've figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a GTK python script to C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045850/convert-a-gtk-python-script-to-c)

Comment: @kaizer.se not really the same question, but my answer to that one works as answer to this :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

9 years passed and as mentioned above API is removed.

As far as I understand, currently the bare minimum to do this at Linux is:

```
GdkWindow * root;
GdkPixbuf * screenshot;
gint x, y, width, height;

root = gdk_get_default_root_window ();
gdk_window_get_geometry (root, &x, &y, &width, &height);
screenshot = gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window (root, x, y, width, height);
// gdk_pixbuf_save...
```

This is very slightly tested and may fail. Further reading is in gnome-screenshooter [repo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot)

Answer (score 11):

After looking at the GNOME-Screenshot code and a Python example, I came up with this:

```
GdkPixbuf * get_screenshot(){
    GdkPixbuf *screenshot;
    GdkWindow *root_window;
    gint x_orig, y_orig;
    gint width, height;
    root_window = gdk_get_default_root_window ();
    gdk_drawable_get_size (root_window, &width, &height);      
    gdk_window_get_origin (root_window, &x_orig, &y_orig);

    screenshot = gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable (NULL, root_window, NULL,
                                           x_orig, y_orig, 0, 0, width, height);
    return screenshot;
}
```

Which seems to work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is now totally outdated and API's are removed since 3.10

Comment: @Lothar on Gtk# 3.24 **Windows** and  **linux on xorg** you can use `new Pixbuf(Gdk.Global.DefaultRootWindow, rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height)`
but it produces a transparent image on **wayland** (correct size but all transparent pixels)

Comment: Well it should only return transparent pixels until you have issued some permission requests first. But does anyone know how to do this? This has become pretty complicated with all the portals we have to use now. And unless Android Wayland programming is much less well documented.