# Screen capture with gtk2hs using gtk3

Tags: haskell, screenshot, capture, gtk2hs

I'm aware that using gtk2 it was possible to capture a screen into a pixbuf using gtk2hs. The solution is given here: [Screen capture in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963561/screen-capture-in-haskell).
The problem is that pixbufGetFromDrawable is absent in gtk3 (at least in gtk2hs). Can somebody recommend the solution to this problem? I need this for linux, not windows.
The solution from the link is duplicated here for convenience.

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Screen
import System.Environment

main = do
  [fileName] <- getArgs
  initGUI
  Just screen <- screenGetDefault
  window <- screenGetRootWindow screen
  size <- drawableGetSize window
  origin <- drawWindowGetOrigin window
  Just pxbuf <- pixbufGetFromDrawable window ((uncurry . uncurry Rectangle) origin size)
  pixbufSave pxbuf filename "png" []
```

Comment: it's worse, the drawableGetSize is absent as well, was replaced by `(width, height) <- windowGetSize window` though