# Screen capture in Haskell with Win32 library

Tags: haskell, winapi

I'm trying to create an app which takes the screenshot of running application.
I've used code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11966931/2064205.
I have a problem with the createBMPFile function, it saves black images. I've tried to create the similar app in C++, also has the same problem.
I'm new in Haskell, do not pay attention to the code.

```
import Graphics.Win32.Window
import Graphics.Win32.GDI.Bitmap
import Graphics.Win32.GDI.HDC
import Graphics.Win32.GDI.Graphics2D
import Graphics.Win32.Window.ForegroundWindow
import Graphics.Win32.GDI.Types (HWND)
import Foreign.Ptr

    getValueFromMaybe :: Maybe HWND -> HWND
    getValueFromMaybe mx = 
        case mx of
            Just value -> value
            Nothing ->  nullPtr

    main = do 
          desktop   <- findWindowByName "slack" -- Grab the Hwnd of the window with title "slack", GetDC 0, GetDC NULL etc all work too
          setForegroundWindow . getValueFromMaybe $ desktop
          desktop   <- findWindowByName "slack"
          hdc       <- getWindowDC desktop -- Get the dc handle of the desktop
          (x,y,r,b) <- getWindowRect . getValueFromMaybe $ desktop -- Find the size of the desktop so we can know which size the destination bitmap should be
                                             -- (left, top, right, bottom)
          newDC     <- createCompatibleDC (Just hdc) -- Create a new DC to hold the copied image. It should be compatible with the source DC
          let width  = r - x -- Calculate the width
          let height = b - y -- Calculate the Height
          newBmp    <- createCompatibleBitmap hdc width height -- Create a new Bitmap which is compatible with the newly created DC
          selBmp    <- selectBitmap newDC newBmp -- Select the Bitmap into the DC, drawing on the DC now draws on the bitmap as well
          bitBlt newDC 0 0 width height hdc 0 0 sRCCOPY -- use SRCCOPY to copy the desktop DC into the newDC
          createBMPFile "Foo.bmp" newBmp newDC  -- Write out the new Bitmap file to Foo.bmp
          putStrLn "Bitmap image copied" -- Some debug message
          deleteBitmap selBmp -- Cleanup the selected bitmap
          deleteBitmap newBmp -- Cleanup the new bitmap
          deleteDC newDC      -- Cleanup the DC we created.
```

Comment: What about some error checking?

Comment: Win32 has error checking functionality, if something went wrong it raises an exception. During the execution of this function, I didn't get exceptions.

Comment: The actual error checking performed in `createBMPFile` is... sub-par: see https://github.com/haskell/win32/blob/master/cbits/dumpBMP.c