# Capturing current desktop view in C

Tags: c, screenshot

Is there a library for C to enable it to take screenshots and save as a .bmp file?

Comment: You need to tell us how you're doing it in Python. What library did you use?

Comment: Lots of good winapi examples out there.

Answer (score 3):

No standard way in C. C doesn't even have the notion of a screen, let alone taking a screenshot.

The library you used in Python presumably has C bindings or at least C source code. You could look into those, or a portable GUI library such as GTK+. Or you could go for your platform's API, but that's usually not worth the frustration.

See [Taking a screenshot with C\GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124229/taking-a-screenshot-with-c-gtk) for a simple GTK+ example.