# save current window as image using gtk#

Tags: gtk, gtk#, gtk2, gdk, gdkpixbuf

How can I save the current window as an image file such as a png?

I know I can get a gdkWindow from current windows. 
I can even get an image. From this image struct I can even query each pixel. But from what I understand what I really need is to get a pixbuf.

```
int width;
int height;
this.GetSize(width, height);
this.GdkWindow.GetImage(0,0,width,height).?
```

How do I get a pixbuf from 
a gtk window or
a gdk window or
a gdk image ?

EDIT

```
int width;
int height;
this.GetSize(out width, out height);
Pixbuf pixbuf = Pixbuf.FromDrawable (this.GdkWindow, this.Colormap, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
pixbuf.Save("/tmp/out.png","png");
```

is kinda working. A png is exported with the correct size but it is blurred.

EDIT 2

The solution is working. The bluriness was a bug of gnome image viewer

Comment: Are you using GTK+2 or 3?

Comment: I would say 2 as gtk-sharp version is 2.12.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gdk2/stable/gdk2-Pixbufs.html#gdk-pixbuf-get-from-drawable) to get from the `GdkWindow` to a `GdkPixbuf`, then if you want to save to a file use [`gdk_pixbuf_save`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/unstable/gdk-pixbuf-File-saving.html#gdk-pixbuf-save).

In Cairo, which is the more future-proof method, you could use [`cairo_image_surface_create`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-image-surface-create), pass the result to [`cairo_create`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-create), pass that to [`gdk_cairo_set_source_window`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gdk2/stable/gdk2-Cairo-Interaction.html#gdk-cairo-set-source-window), copy to your image surface with [`cairo_paint`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-paint), and write your image with [`cairo_surface_write_to_png`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-PNG-Support.html#cairo-surface-write-to-png).

Also note that your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787458/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-particular-window-with-c-gtk). However, since the answer to that question does not work, if my answer answers your question, I'll close the other question as a dupe of this.

Comment: Just before you call `cairo_surface_write_to_png`, make sure you call [`cairo_paint`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-paint) on your `cairo_t`.

Comment: Thanks @Jason. I'll readily admit I didn't test any of this answer and in fact I have no experience with GDK pixbufs or Cairo image backends. I just know my way around GTK and Cairo docs is all. I guess your suggested call is a little bit necessary, isn't it? (Good thing OP didn't use Cairo :) )